# JWT architecture for multiple users?

Tags: jwt

Most examples always take into consideration only one users using the system in the JWT/Flask tutorials. I want to understand this at a multi-user level but cannot find the correct resources.

Lets say we have the following secret key:

`app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'randomkey'`

Two Questions:

- Would this key be the same for every user? if so, wouldn't this provide a security risk because if the key was stolen, anyone would have access to do whatever they want?
- If it is not the same, how is the key stored on the server-side so it could be authenticated when requesting information? Would it be stored within the user's table under current token or something?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, that key is the JWT signing key It could also be different from flask's secret key setting (see [flask docs](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/)). It's not used for encryption so it's not intended to be a shared secret between server and users. Its role is to provide the server with a proof that the JWT content was generated by the server itself: it's a proof of integrity.

Having knowledge of that key means having the right to issue JWTs on behalf of the application, attackers could impersonate servers or make requests with some modified claims, eg pretending to be other users. This means that these keys are quite sensible from security perspective

Turns out that 1 app : 1 key, with some remarks

1. This key should theorically never change: if at time T1 KEY=x, a user could login in and receive a JWT signed with KEY=x. at T2 KEY=y, the user will invoke some API using the previous JWT and the server will try to verify(signature(payload , x) , y). So every user will be logged out automatically
2. Despite 1. It would be good to rotate the key. In this case the authentication system should save a buffer of old keys and use them to validate oldest JWT. Since a JWT should be short-lived, it could be useful set a rotation time grater than JWT expire time and just keep the last used key along with the current
3. This key is a secret and should be managed exactly as other secrets. Aside from terrible approaches like leaving it plaintext in the code/config, there are secret managers from cloud providers, or kubernetes secrets if you use the latter, as well as secret managers from configuration management tools (salt, ansible) or [Hashicorp's Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) that is a specialized storage engine for sensible data. Anyway, it's more infra/security team concern if you are in a structured organization